# Как заблокировать клавиатуру и мышь?

Tags: c#

Просто как заблокировать клавиатуру и мышь? Уже смотрел эту страницу http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread595784.html

но этот код не работает при запуске приложения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение 1:

Можно отключить питание в устройства. Ответ как это делать я давал вот здесь:

[Включение / отключение USB портов или устройств](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/891397/%d0%92%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-usb-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2/901814#901814)

Решение 2:

Можно через WIN API перехватывать отменять любой сигнал с нужного устройства.

Решение 3:

Можно через WIN API заблокировать сам инпут:

```
public partial class NativeMethods {

    /// Return Type: BOOL->int
    ///fBlockIt: BOOL->int
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint="BlockInput")]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern  bool BlockInput([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fBlockIt) ;

}

public static void BlockInput(TimeSpan span) {
  try { 
    NativeMethods.BlockInput(true);
    Thread.Sleep(span);
  } finally {
    NativeMethods.BlockInput(false);
  }
}
```

Как видно из метода, он просто блочит инпут ***с мышки и клавиатуры*** на некоторое время заданное через ТаймСпан. Думаю, разобраться будет не сложно.

ответ найден вот здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586547/how-can-i-block-keyboard-and-mouse-input-in-c

последний найден по запросу "api block mouse input c#"

Comment: Ыыыы, какая классная идея для первоапрельской шутки! Лайк однозначно! )) Если коллега зазевался - надо ему отключить мышку на час, пусть поплюётся вспоминая клавиатурные сочетания. ))

Comment: Спасибо! Решение 3 работает, но только при запуске приложения от имени администратора.

Comment: Скорее всего вторую часть ты пихаешь не внутрь какого-то класса. Или все решение пихаешь уже в какой-то существующий класс. Короче, я проверил, код работает.  Я не знаю какие ошибки у тебя лезут :) Но решение рабочее 100%.

Comment: @AK лучше втихую замени символ точки с запятой в его проэкте на такой же визуально, но с другим кодом ASCII... Кажеться GeekQuote зовется или что-то такое... Кароч всюду будут ошибки о том, что там нету точки с запятой, даже, если они там визуально будут.... Доведешь человека до белой гарячки :D

Comment: А еще можно просто заблокировать введение ";". То есть все кнопки оставить рабочими, а вот хуком отменять введение этого символа.... Вот человек охренеет, если клавиша работает на других раскладках, а конкретный символ не вводится....

Comment: А еще можно вообще зло сделать... Создать свою раскладку клавиатуры английской и заменить точку с запятой на тот GeekQuote. Это будет вообще ЗЛО.